# Calculate multiple records in the same day in the same location as a single visit

Tags: tableau-api

The Postgres database has a table for photos with Datetime and store names.  Usually, there will be multiple photo records on a given day for a given store name.
I want to aggregate photos for the same day in the same store as a **single store visit** so I can calculate the number of visits in a month.

This is what I have tried...

```
CountStoreVisits = COUNTD(DATE([AEDTcreatedAt]))
CountOfVisitsPerStore = {FIXED [Store Name] : [CountStoresVisits]}
```

This kinda works but I'm not able to total the total number of store visits per month.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around I remembered that you can add more than one dimension in the LOD. So this was the solution that worked for me.

```
CountOfVisitsPerStore = {FIXED [Store Name], DATETRUNC('day', [AEDTcreatedAt]) : [CountStoresVisits]}
```